# How to add focus on a tag in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `react-router`'s `IndexLink`:

```
<IndexLink to="/">Home</IndexLink>
```

I can see that it creates an `<a>` tag, but how can I style it with

```
a:focus {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `style.js` file, and give its reference in `index.html` page. Put this style in `style.js`, it will automatically get applied on all `a` tags.